# ExecuteCommand throwing "The method or operation is not implemented" exception

Tags: c#, wia

In WIA, ExecuteCommand is getting exception:

```
The method or operation is not implemented
```

Code:

```
WIA.CommonDialog dialog = new WIA.CommonDialog();
WIA.Device camera = dialog.ShowSelectDevice(WIA.WiaDeviceType.CameraDeviceType, false, true);
WIA.Item takenItem = camera.ExecuteCommand("{AF933CAC-ACAD-11D2-A093-00C04F72DC3C}");
```

Any help.....?

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting error you have maybe unsuitable camera. Microsoft canceled WIA library many years ago and newest digital cameras do not support WIA protocol.
Here is a short list of suitable cameras:

Digital IXUS 430
Digital IXUS 500
Digital IXUS IIs
PowerShot A310
PowerShot A400
PowerShot A75
PowerShot A85
PowerShot A95
PowerShot Pro1
PowerShot S1 IS
PowerShot S60

and also (maybe):

```
Agfa ePhoto 307
Agfa ePhoto 780
Agfa ePhoto 1280
Agfa ePhoto 1680
Canon PowerShot A5
Canon PowerShot A5 Zoom
Canon PowerShot Pro70
Casio QV 10
Casio QV 10A
Casio QV 11
Casio QV 30
Casio QV 70
Casio QV 100
Casio QV 120
Casio QV 200
Casio QV 300
Casio QV 700
Casio QV 770
Casio QV 5000SX
Casio QV-770 (IrTran-P)
Casio QV-5000SX (IrTran-P)
Casio QV-7000SX (IrTran-P)
Epson PhotoPC / CP-100
Epson PhotoPC 500 / CP-200
Epson PhotoPC 600 / CP-500
Epson PhotoPC 700 / CP-600
Epson PhotoPC 750Z / CP-700Z
FujiFilm DX-5/DS-10
FujiFilm DX-7/DS-20
FujiFilm DX-9/DS-30
FujiFilm MX-700
FujiFilm DS-300
HP PhotoSmart C20
HP PhotoSmart C30
HP PhotoSmart C200
JVC GCS1 (IrTran-P)
Kodak DC200
Kodak DC210
Kodak DC215
Kodak DC220 (USB only)
Kodak DC260 (USB only)
Kodak DC265 (USB only)
Kodak DC290 (USB only)
Kodak DC240 (USB only)
Kodak DC280 (USB only)
Konica Q-M100
Konica Q-M100V
Minolta Dimage V
Nikon CoolPix 900
Nikon CoolPix 950
Nikon CoolPix 700
Olympus D-200L
Olympus D-220L
Olympus D-300L
Olympus D-320L
Olympus D-340L
Olympus D-340R
Olympus D-500L
Olympus D-600L
Olympus D-400Z
Sanyo DSC-V1/VPC-G200
Sanyo DSC-X1/VPC-X300
Sharp VE-LC2 (IrTran-P)
Sony DSC-F3 (IrTran-P)
UMAX AstraCam (USB)
UMAX AstraCam 1000 (USB)
```

Newest digital cameras such as Canon IXUS 162,170,180 etc. does NOT support WIA protocol. If you are looking for a replacement of the old "take a picture" WIA 1.x/2.x command: {AF933CAC-ACAD-11D2-A093-00C04F72DC3C} , the suitable way is Canon EOS series and CanonSDK library.

jerry